# python to R compatibility in feather with strings

Tags: python, r, pandas, feather

I am hitting an error when reading a feather object into R that was put out from a python session.

**In python:**

```
In [248]: import pandas as pd

In [249]: pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a','b','c']}).to_feather('strings_df.feather')
```

**In R:**

```
> library(feather)
> df = read_feather('strings_df.feather')
Error in coldataFeather(x, i) : 
  RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'list'
```

Is this related to the fact that strings are stored as objects in `pandas.Series`?  *Any thoughts on what's happening here?*

**Session info:**

R

> R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
>   (64-bit) Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)
>
> locale: [1]
>   en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] feather_0.3.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] assertthat_0.1 hms_0.2 
>   tools_3.3.1    tibble_1.2     Rcpp_0.12.5

Python

> '2.7.10 (default, Jul  3 2015,
>   12:05:53) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]'
>
> Pandas version: '0.20.3'
>
> Numpy version: '1.13.1'

Comment: Probably also worth noting the versions of packages that you are using pandas, etc.

Comment: Please include all library lines in R. Unlike pandas, not all methods are in one.

Comment: @lmo Updated with additional session info.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simply that values in a string column should be of type `unicode`, not `str`.  The following works as expected:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col': [u'a',u'b',u'c']}).to_feather('strings_df.feather')
```